# Migrating Exchange public folder to SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-2007, exchange-server-2003

I have been reading a number of articles online suggesting different approaches to migrate data in an Exchange public folder to a SharePoint Library.

Our company has a list of items tracked inside an Exchange public folder. It is just a bunch of data columns and we have to move that data to SharePoint and start using SharePoint instead.

Does anyone know how to handle this programatically? Or if it is too much work, a tool that is known to handle this well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing code to handle this myself.